# Compile 32 bit and 64 bit application (with same code) into one exe

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I have 2 applications that uses global hooks, and its built for Windows 10 (64 bit). One is 32 bit and the other is 64 bit. I am able to compile them into 2 separate exe files that work independently. But since they have the same code, I wish to compile them into one exe file that will cater to both it's 32 bit and 64 bit responsibilities. Can I do that using Visual Studio or other means?

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: It's called a [*fat binary*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_binary) and is not supported on Windows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Windows PE EXE format does not support multiple CPU architectures in a single binary.

The SysInternals tools embed the 64-bit .exe as a resource in the 32-bit executable and extracts and runs that if [`IsWow64Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684139(v=vs.85).aspx) is true. If you choose this technique you must also take into account that the recent ARM64 machines are Wow64 but only emulate 32-bit x86 applications.

Note: Windows Server Core can be installed without Wow64 support and you must also distribute the 64-bit binary if you support those systems.

Comment: I guess technically the EXE formats supports one >= 32-bit target **and** a 16-bit DOS target but that is not really relevant these days.